# regex to fetch url from string

Tags: php, regex

In php am doing one task -
I want such a regex which will fetch like

```
$str = "this is my friend's website http://example1.com I think it is coll some text example.com some text t.com/2000 some text rs.500 some text http://www some text"
```

how can I fetch following with the help of regex -

```
http://example1.com
example.com
t.com/2000
http://www
```

rs.500 must be avoided!

actually I need such a regex which can satisfy any link

please help me with that

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: [Testing, Testing, 1 2 3](http://www.regextester.com/?fam=95928)

Comment: @DanielDudas I have tried but it gives me only those urls which has https or http..... can you please help me out here I am still trying .... If I will get an answer I will definitely update it here ....

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex is what you're looking for ([mandatory regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/u2V85K/1)):

```
(https?:\/\/\S+)|([a-z]+\.[a-z]+(?:\/\S+)?)
```

It's basically the two regexes `https?:\/\/\S+` and `[a-z]+\.[a-z]+(?:\/\S+)?` placed into capturing groups (so that you can extract all URLs with a global search) and then combined with an OR.

`https?:\/\/\S+` finds URLs that are prefixed with `http://` or `https://` by matching:

- The string "http" literally `http`, followed by
- An optional "s" `s?` followed by
- A colon and two forward slashes `:\/\/`, followed by
- One or more non-whitespace characters `\S+`

If `https?:\/\/\S+` doesn't match, then `[a-z]+\.[a-z]+(?:\/\S+)?` kicks in and finds URLs that are **not** prefixed with `http://` or `https://` and whose top level domains don't contain numbers by matching:

- One or more lowercase letters `[a-z]+`, followed by
- A dot `\.`, followed by
- One or more lowercase letters `[a-z]+`, followed by
- An optional group, which consists of

  - A forward slash `\/`, followed by
  - One or more non-whitespace characters `\S+`