# How do I apply a URL in a string?

Tags: reactjs

I have some data in an object that I'm iterating through, and I'm pulling a property (string) from this object to render to the screen.

The object looks like this:

```
 `object: { id: 1, sample: 'To learn all about React, click here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)' }`
```

I did lots of research and a lot of the answers pointed to using the Linkify plugin. I set up the Linkify plugin like so:

```
<Linkify>{sample}</Linkify>
```

This works good but I'm wondering if I'm able to modify the string so that I'm not displaying the actual address and instead, could I assign the address to the word 'here'. For example:

```
'To learn all about React, click `here`'.
```

Is this possible with the Linkify plugin or do I have to do something different?

Comment: how are u implementing this? can we see some code?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this with react as well. Create a link component, that accepts 2 props. {url} and {link}.

hyperLink.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default ({ text, link }) =>{
   return(
      <a href={link}> {text} </a>
   )
}
```

Then import into your index your index.js

```
import Hyperlink from './hyperLink'

<div>
   To learn more about react click <Hyperlink link={#} text="here">
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that the name of your props in your text is different from their names in the code itself. Also, I'm not sure your code works, since you're passing `text, link` as parameters and then you're accessing them via `props`, which doesn't exist :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try parsing the string to fetch the url from it. and then use the url as the value to the href attribute in a tag./
To fetch the url you could use regex.

```
(https?:\/\/\S+)|([a-z]+\.[a-z]+(?:\/\S+)?)
```

I tried using the regex to parse your string and it totally works.
I have taken this regex from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39944457/10100750. You could see the link to know about this regex further.